# Losing data in avd file when creating a new virtual device - Android Studio

Tags: android, virtual

I am a newbie in Android Studio. At the step of creating a new virtual device, I chose the phone named Pixel 4 (Size 5.7) and the system image Oreo (Android 8.0). But whenever I click on the Finish button, it always shows me a message: **"An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details."**. But then I realize that when I click the Finish button, there are 2 files appearing in the *avd file (C:\Users\admin.android\avd)* but then they disappear immediately.

I have been searching for solutions on the Internet for a week but it doesn't help. I hope if you have experienced this problem before and know the solution, just tell me cause I am in an emergency right now.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As you click finish, android studio understands that the avd has not been created, thus it will delete useless files.

Comment: The files you are saying might be useless for it, thus it is deleting them..